# Google URL Crawl error 404 - domain appending to end of URL

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, web-crawler, permalinks

I recently built and published my Wordpress site at [www.kernelops.com](http://www.kernelops.com) and submitted it to the google index and webmaster tools.  Today I logged into webmaster tools and found 60 URL errors all with the same type of issue.  The base domain address [www.kernelops.com](http://www.kernelops.com) is being appended to all  my sites page, category, and post URLs.  An example of the failed URL looks like this:

http://[www.kernelops.com](http://www.kernelops.com)/blog/www.kernelops.com

Google Webmaster Tools indicates that this weird link is originating from the base url "http://www.kernelops.com/blog" which obviously means the issue is on my end.  My Wordpress permalink settings are set to use the post-name; I'm not sure if that could be causing this, i.e.:

http://[www.kernelops.com](http://www.kernelops.com)/sample-post/

I can't seem to find any help resolving this weird issue with google searches and thought someone here may be able to point me in the right direction.

The Wordpress plugins that would potentially affect the site's URLs are the following:

- All in One SEO
- XML-Sitemap

But I can't see any sort of setting within these plugins that would be causing this type of issue.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot, but it may be happening if the Google crawler picks up a link that seems like a relative path and attempts to append it to the current directory. It's **highly unlikely** that Google would have such a bug, but it's not impossible either.

The closes thing I could find that may be considered a relative path is this:

```
<div class="copyright">
...
<a href="www.kernelops.com">Kernel, Inc.</a>
...
</div>
```

I doubt that this is the problem, but it may be worth fixing it.

Now, there is yet another possibility and that's if the website serves slightly different content depending on the User Agent string. When Google presents your website with a User Agent string, the SEO plugins detects it and tries to optimize things in order to improve your ranking (not familiar with that plugins, so I don't know what it does exactly). There may be a bug in the SEO plugin that will cause the `www.kernelops.com` URL to look like a relative path or to actually construct that faulty URL somehow.

You can possibly test this by setting the user-agent string in your browser (e.g. [FireFox's user-agent switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)) to [Googlebot's user-agent string](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1061943) and test what happens when you visit your website. Look at the page source that you receive and look for any links that might look like the one Google is finding.

*However, if the SEO tool is smart enough, it will "realize" that your IP doesn't match one of the valid IPs for Googlebot and it will not make the modifications.*

Comment: Great, thanks for the suggestions.  I've fixed the copyright link to add http:// infront.  It will take a little while for google to notice the change and re-crawl so I'll get back with an update on that in a few days.  I'll give the user-agent string thing a try and get back with you... thanks again

Comment: @sadmicrowave Like I said: it's very unlikely that Google would have such a bug, but it's worth a try. I will be VERY surprised if that was the problem.